# R Divide all rows of a dataframe column by a number

Tags: r, dataframe, divide

I am trying to divide all rows of my dataframe column by a number (say 10). I thought it to be a trivial problem until I tried it. In the example below, I am trying to get the 'mm' column to result in values 8100, 3222.2 and 5433.3

```
test <- data.frame(locations=c("81000","32222","54333"), value=c(87,54,43))
test$mm <- as.numeric(test$locations) / 10
head(test)
     locations value  mm
   1     81000    87 0.3
   2     32222    54 0.1
   3     54333    43 0.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: locations is not a number, it's a character, remove the commas

Comment: Either specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` within `data.frame` or don't quote `locations` (e.g., `locations=c(81000,32222,54333)`), or see the dupe target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `factors` to be `character`, then apply `as.numeric`

```
> test$mm <- as.numeric(as.character(test$locations)) / 10
> test
  locations value     mm
1     81000    87 8100.0
2     32222    54 3222.2
3     54333    43 5433.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works. I did not realize that my column was a factor rather than a character. I will accept the answer.